# how can I send many MongoDB queries in one database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I want to render 2 MongoDB queries from the same collection.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    Post.find({}, function(err, posts) {
        res.render("home", {
            latestPosts: posts
        });
    }).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1);

    Post.find({}, function(err, posts) {
        res.render("home", {
            otherPost: posts
        });
    }).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(2);
});
```

the first one (latestPosts) renders successfully but the second one (otherPost) shows an error as
`otherPost is not defined`.

Please help me, sorry if my question is too easy as I am a newbie in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are Trying to render the same view ("home") twice in the same route handler function, and each render call overwrites the previous one

*This is why the otherPost variable is undefined in the second render call.*

Try this Method.

```
  app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      Post.find({}) 
        .sort({ _id: -1 })
        .limit(2)
        .exec(function(err, posts) {
          if (err) {
           console.log(err)
          }

      const latestPost = posts[0];
      const otherPost = posts[1];

      res.render("home", {
        latestPost: latestPost,
        otherPost: otherPost
      });
    });
});
```